# Consise method of re-ordering primary SQL keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Solved** my solution at bottom

---

I'm working on a system that is built around using the primary key of an SQL table to sort things. I'm trying to add the ability in the UI to reorder this sorting.

Ideally I'd like a concise and efficient general solution that wouldn't involve duplicating the whole table. I would also the solution to not require rewriting the whole system to use a different key/id if possible.

The best (in my opinion) solution I've come up with doesn't seem to work and I can't quite figure out why.

```
$old_ids = $_POST["oldid"];
$new_ids = $_POST["newid"];
$i = 0;
foreach ($old_ids as $oid) {
    $nid = $new_ids[$i];
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET sort = $oid WHERE id = $oid");
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET id = -$nid WHERE sort = $oid");
    $i++;
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($old_ids as $oid) {
    $nid = $new_ids[$i];
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET id = $nid WHERE id = -$oid");
    $i++;
}
$db->insert("UPDATE links SET sort = NULL");
```

That PHP outputs the SQL when moving the top row (Row 1) to the bottom (Row 6)

```
UPDATE links SET sort = 2 WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE links SET id = -1 WHERE sort = 2;
UPDATE links SET sort = 3 WHERE id = 3;
UPDATE links SET id = -2 WHERE sort = 3;
UPDATE links SET sort = 4 WHERE id = 4;
UPDATE links SET id = -3 WHERE sort = 4;
UPDATE links SET sort = 5 WHERE id = 5;
UPDATE links SET id = -4 WHERE sort = 5;
UPDATE links SET sort = 6 WHERE id = 6;
UPDATE links SET id = -5 WHERE sort = 6;
UPDATE links SET sort = 1 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE links SET id = -6 WHERE sort = 1;
UPDATE links SET id = 1 WHERE id = -2;
UPDATE links SET id = 2 WHERE id = -3;
UPDATE links SET id = 3 WHERE id = -4;
UPDATE links SET id = 4 WHERE id = -5;
UPDATE links SET id = 5 WHERE id = -6;
UPDATE links SET id = 6 WHERE id = -1
```

When I run it in phpmyadmin, with all of the IDs reset to their default 1-6 (positive) values, I get the following error

```
UPDATE links SET id = -5 WHERE sort = 6;
#1062 - Duplicate entry '-5' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I haven't yet seen anything that seems to resolve this issue of key duplication in an efficient or concise way. If no particularly concise or efficient method exists to resolve this problem, what is the most efficient way to approach it?

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious, but I haven't been able to come to a solution yet. Any help or insight on how to accomplish what I need would be greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against this for several hours.

### **Solution**

So here's what I came up with that seems to achieve what I wanted.

```
$old_ids = $_POST["oldid"];
$new_ids = $_POST["newid"];
$i = 0;
$db->insert("ALTER TABLE links CHANGE id id INT(255) NOT NULL");
foreach ($old_ids as $oid) {
    $nid = $new_ids[$i];
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET id = -$nid WHERE id = $oid");
    $i++;
}
foreach ($old_ids as $oid) {
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET id = $oid WHERE id = -$oid");
}
$db->insert("ALTER TABLE links CHANGE id id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
```

The trick was to temporarily toggle `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` column. In addition to this I realized that a dedicated `sort` column wasn't needed at all.

Obviously this needs some error handling, but I hope the general idea of toggling `AUTO_INCREMENT`, setting the new `id` value as a negative, iterating through to invert them to positives will help someone facing the same problem.

Comment: The most likely explanation for the behavior seems like there's already a row in your table that has `id` value of -5, or, there are two rows that have a `sort` value of 6, when that statement runs. Re-assigning primary key values to achieve a sort order seems very odd. One of the desirable properties of a primary key is that it is immutable (once assigned, it doesn't change.) That's not a hard requirement of primary keys, but we do find it desirable.

Comment: My first suggestion is to rule out the possibility of an existing row with `sort=6`. I'd suggest you first run that update statement that clears out the `sort` column. (If a previous run of this process didn't run to completion, that last statement may not have been executed.). You could also run it again at the end. (Is there any mechanism that prevents two copies of this procedure from running at the same time?)

Comment: Please post your solution below as a proper answer. Then when the minimum time has expired, return to it and click the checkmark to mark it as "accepted", as that is how the community knows your question has been addressed.

Comment: Will do. Wasn't sure the proper way to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I came up with that seems to achieve what I wanted.

```
$old_ids = $_POST["oldid"];
$new_ids = $_POST["newid"];
$i = 0;
$db->insert("ALTER TABLE links CHANGE id id INT(255) NOT NULL");
foreach ($old_ids as $oid) {
    $nid = $new_ids[$i];
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET id = -$nid WHERE id = $oid");
    $i++;
}
foreach ($old_ids as $oid) {
    $db->insert("UPDATE links SET id = $oid WHERE id = -$oid");
}
$db->insert("ALTER TABLE links CHANGE id id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
```

The trick was to temporarily toggle `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` column. In addition to this I realized that a dedicated `sort` column wasn't needed at all.

Obviously this needs some error handling, but I hope the general idea of toggling `AUTO_INCREMENT`, setting the new `id` value as a negative, iterating through to invert them to positives will help someone facing the same problem.